# ArcGIS 10.1 Cost Distance Calculations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, distance, spatial-analyst

I have a study area that is a polygon feature class, and am running the Cost Distance Tool on it in ModelBuilder. However, everytime I run the tool, it only calculates a cost distance and cost distance backlink for half of the polygon. The cost surface I produced with a weighted overlay covers the entirety of the study area, but not the cost distance. Any suggestions as to how to go about resolving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the processing extent to the study zone polygon.

Comment: I've already set the processing extent to the study area for everything.. I tried re running it a few times, but still no luck..It stops halfway through from the endpoint and never reaches the start point